# Django - delete multiple models in a record

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm having a problem I would like to know if you could help me out.

I'm having a `table` where I'm showing three different models and that's working ok.

My problem is when I want to delete that record, as you know I have to specify which model I'm picking so I can delete it. I used to do it with three different `tables` one table for each model, but now as I made one table for the three models I have no clue how to do it.

I've been trying different ways but nothing worked.

Here's what I got:

Views.py

```
def eliminar_activos(request, id):
    opc = activo_opc.objects.get(id=id) #first model
    odbc = activo_odbc.objects.get(id=id) #second model
    eip = activo_eip.objects.get(id=id)# third model
    delete = chain(opc,odbc ,eip )
    delete.delete()
    messages.success(request, "Success!")
    return redirect('activo')
```

Urls.py

```
url(r'^eliminar_activos/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.eliminar_activos, name='eliminar_activos'),
```

Template:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'eliminar_activos' item.id %}"> Eliminar </a> </td>
```

note:

only works with first model, not working with the rest.

if I try with the other two models I got this error:

> activo_opc matching query does not exist.

Is there a possible way to do it without having three tables? 
**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is weird is you remove rows from 3 different models based on a same given id, is it intended?

You should have a relation between your three models.
Probably a OneToOneField for each other models.

Check this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Then you can configure your oneToOneField so that when you delete the row, it also deletes the other object of the relation :

```
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return "%s the place" % self.name

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    place = models.OneToOneField(
        Place,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, # deleting a place will delete the associated restaurant
        primary_key=True,
    )
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return "%s the restaurant" % self.place.name
```

Comment: That way can I delete multiple models with same ID? for example I want to delete some model and keep others. Will it work?

Comment: yes, if you don't want them to be removed you just don't define a "on_delete" attribute on the relation

Comment: Thanks! well explained. Have one last question, no matter how many models I have? say I have Restaurant 2,3,4. Can I delete Restaunt 1 and Restaunt 4? both of them having on_delete on model?. thank you.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, and the answer is no.
Your data model seems special

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Delete multiple models in a `table` , I'm using `itertools` to chain 3 differentes queryset of three differentes models, `activo_eip.objects.all()`, activo_odbc.objects.all` and `activo_opc.objects.all()`, and I'm take data out from models in  a `table`using for example `item.name`and `item.place` , having multiple models in a `table`I want to delete any of them.

Comment: Any possible way to delete for example `item.name` from `activo_eip` and `item.name`from `activo_opc`? in the same `table`